# Is there any way to tell if the early Mufassir (Commentators) were influenced by Israʼiliyyat ( Jewish Stories)

Tags: tafseer

In the qu'ran 26:54 it says " "Indeed, those are but a small band" regarding the exodus but in the tafsir i have seen that the isrealites were more than 600,000! for example

"ن هؤلاء لشرذمة"، عصابة "قليلون"، والشرذمة القطعة من الناس غير الكثير، وجمعها شراذم. قال أهل التفسير: كانت الشرذمة الذين قللهم فرعون ستمائة ألف. وعن ابن مسعود قال: كانوا ستمائة وسبعين ألفاً ولا يحصى عدد أصحاب فرعون"

No matter how you look it at, more than 600,000 not a small band (Also such a number is not likely to be historically accurate considering the population size of Ancient Egypt). This number also coincides with the number found in the bible. So is it possible this number was from jewish stories?

Comment: Which tafsir are you referring to?

Comment: For example in Tafsir Tabari for example

Answer (score -1):

The Prophet is said to be 'unlettered' meaning that he was divinely inspired when it came to the Qu'ran. It's also said that he is also a man, though a man different from others, given his mobility of soul and his prophethood.

We do not have the historical records to show what the Prophet was influenced by in the human world. Much of what is said, is speculation and conjecture without a concrete, historically based foundation.

Comment: I'm not talking about the prophet but much rather the early commentators

Comment: @user40139: But you don't quote from them; you wiote from the Qu'ran and hence my answer. What evidence do you have that the early commentaties were so influenced?